# Flexslider mobile layout

Tags: jquery, css, flexslider

Im having issues with flexslider where on mobile the image will be too zoomed in.

I have tried to have a separate slider for mobile that displays smaller images but they too are zoomed in.

Is there a way to either zoom out of the image or when on on a mobile swap the images out for smaller files?

Comment: What have you tried ? Stack Overflow is not a free coding service.try to  Search and research and try writing some code. 
If you then have trouble, you can come back here and ask a proper question, providing [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In head section, have you this? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: @GermanoPlebani yes

Comment: @jason try setting `max-width:100%` with `display:block` to your `img` tag